# Disable Alt key from accessing Windows menu/ causing menu acceleration

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Basically when you press Alt it activates the window menu (indicated by a small underscore), so when you then press any other key it opens up a dropdown if it is a valid combination (example Alt+F drops down file menu, Alt+E does the edit menu etc) or it gives the default windows beep if it is invalid.

I've tried using autohotkey in various ways but the most success I managed was switching the Alt key off altogether but that isn't what I want, I just want its functionality where it goes into the window menu removed but still work in other ways.

Comment: In your own application or a 3rd-party application?

Answer (score 5):

This disables the activation of the menu bar when LAlt is pressed  without disabling other LAlt + key combinations:

```
~LAlt::Send {Blind}{vkE8}
```

Comment: This works brilliantly. I see that {vkE8} is a sort of NOOP key but can anyone explain the {Bind} and "why" this works?

Comment: @cfm , {Blind} does not suppress Alt completely, instead its used to avoid releasing any modifier that is bind to the key but still allow the key to perform whatever order you put behind it, in this case "vkE8" which is an empty unassigned order , kind of using "void(0)", which Microsoft documents as "unassigned", or {vkFF} which is reserved to mean "no mapping" (a key which has no function ).

Comment: I can not thank you enough. Now I can use alt for binding AHK commands without tripping menu popups